# Eclipse: Prohibit projects' cross reference

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two projects A and B. Project B is an adaptation of A for another problem, i.e. it is partially a copy of A. So there are similar class names in A and B. Some of these classes are are not yet implemented in B, but used in code. **PROBLEM:** The compiler doesn't tell me that they are not implemented and references to the same classes in A. Others are present in B. **PROBLEM**: The compiler still references these "other" classes to the corresponding classes in A and not in B.

I need the compiler to stop looking for the classes in A, and let me know if a class is not yet implemented in B.

How can I prohibit cross references to other projects loaded into Eclipse workspace?

Edit:

- There is no project A under Java Build Path -> Project in the B's properties.
- There are no projects selected under Project References, also not the project A to which it is referenced from B.
- Deleting the referenced project A from eclipse would solve the problem, but I need it to stay loaded in the same Eclipse session.

Your help is very welcome!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem but can't you just remove the project's references so that A doesn't reference B and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the 'Java Build Path' page of the 'Properties' for project B. On the 'Projects' tab of the properties remove any reference to project A.

Comment: The list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, I needed to add certain folders as sources (right mouse click on the folder in Eclipse Project Explorer -> Build Path -> Use as Source Folder), so that the compiler searches for classes of a package in these added source folders and not in other projects that have the same packages (package names).